# How to get another table from the same sql data source without having to type the server name and database name again?

Tags: powerbi

In power bi, how do I get another table from the same sql data source without having to type the server name and database name again?

Sorry if this is a very silly question, I am a beginner on this tool.

Let's say I already loaded one table from the database. Now I realize I need another table. I click the SQL server in the data section of the toolbar/ribbon:

[image]

When I do that I am again presented with this prompt asking me for the server name and database name again, when I already have this data source defined and connected. Why not a simple dropdown list? How do I simply pick a connection that I already added and browse the tables again?

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click Recent Sources right next to it. Alternatively, copy an existing query and delete all but the first couple of steps.

Comment: "Recent Sources" drop down is the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you already know that you need to import more than one table from a SQL database it is **best practice** to use a basic *landing query* and then start all subordinate table queries by just **referencing** the *landing query*. This way you avoid duplicating the steps of selecting a certain SQL server and database, and probably other pre-processing steps, multiple times.

And always remember this basic programming principle: DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would take what @Peter said a step further: **functionalize** your basic SQL pickup query for its **server, db, query, and a query-fold target**. E.g., this is what I use in all my models:

```
    let
        db =
            Sql.Database(
                #"SQL server",
                #"SQL db",
                [HierarchicalNavigation = true]
            ),
        #"sql" = #"SQL query",
        #"result" =
            Value.NativeQuery(
                db,
                sql,
                null,
                [EnableFolding = true]
            )
    in
        #"result"
```